# Attaching Email in Lotus Notes 8

Tags: email, lotus-notes, attachments

How can I attach an older email message that I received to a new email message that I am composing in Lotus Notes 8?  Or, is there a way to save an email as a file?  Then that file could be attached like any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's a little convoluted, but I figured out how to do it.  For each email to be saved as an attachment...

1. Open it in Notes, select the entire thing (Ctrl+A), and paste it into Word.
2. Do a "Save As..." in Word, and save the file as a Single File Web Page (*.mht).
3. Change the file extension of the saved file from `.mht` to `.eml`.
4. The saved emails (.eml files) can be attached to the new message.

Comment: So I heard a lot of complains about MS Outlook, but now after reading this & working with Lotus Notes for some time - I just wondering how this "convenient/user-friendly" email client can be tolerated on such a scale (number of implementations / user base) / prolonged period of time (i.e. still alive and well) :) Obviously this system should has some hidden gems (has it?) which absolutely not visible to end-users

Comment: Come on, Lotus Notes, you can do better. Attach email is just a simple thing. Why one has to use an external application to help out? Notes is drafted by the easy of use of Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

The `.eml` attachment though can be viewer only if you are using MS outlook.

So this means, you can send the attachment using Lotus Notes but cannot watch it in Lotus Notes itself, this is a handicap here.

Answer (score 1):

Inbox hit shift click on the emails you want to send hit forward. This allows you to join emails that are not related to each other.

Comment: Sorry I don't find this answer to be useful. The action suggested just join emails, but then what? How to attach?

Answer (score 0):

The method I use to do that in any email client is to open or select the old email and use the `Forward` function. Then I type the new message and do `Send`.

Comment: Right, I know how to forward an email.  Like you said, that is supported in any email client.  In Outlook one can attach any number of prior emails to a new email message.  I take it that is not possible with Notes.  Do you know if there is at least a way to save an email as a file?  Then one could attach that file, like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 8.5.2 dragging an email to the filesystem will result in an .eml file. Or from the help: -> Now you can save emails as .eml files. With an email message open, click File > Save As and select the .eml file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reply to a message and attach another one (eg when there are multiple threads about one topic), one way is:

1. Open the reply in a new window
2. In the first window, find the message you want to attach and drag it into the new window

This puts a link in the reply.

Comment: I have tried it our but it does not work in other computer. I mean for example, I sent the email to other person in my company and attached another email like the way you said. But the person to whom I have sent the mail he cannot open the attached email.

Answer (score 0):

Create your new message that you will be attaching the old email to.  Open Lotus inbox (or other folder list that contains the old email that you wish to insert into the new message).  Without opening the old email, drag and drop the message to the body of your new message.  It attaches as a Lotus Notes link icon, however if you then send the email to an internet address, the link converts to a file.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible in Notes 8.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this I created a word doc and copy pasted the old e-mail. Then attched the Word doc to the new e-mail.

Frustrating that LN cannot come up with something like Outlook to simply drag and drop the old e-mail as an attachment.

Comment: This is the same as the three-year-old accepted answer, but less detailed.